# Pandas Dataframe field comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas Dataframe, Lets call one accounts and one entities. Accounts have limited information and Entities have full.

I need to match these and produce accurate results; This is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import jellyfish
import time

reference_data = pd.read_csv('data/f1.csv')
target_data = pd.read_csv('data/entities.csv')

dt = {
    'Account': [],
    'Matched With': [],
    'Comparison Score': [],
    'Accuracy': []
}

final = pd.DataFrame(dt)

def scale_score(score):
    min_score = 0
    max_score = 1684
    scaled_score = (score - min_score) / (max_score - min_score) * 100
    scaled_score = max(0, min(scaled_score, 100))
    return scaled_score

def compare_dataframes(d1, d2, weights):
    fields = ['Display Name', 'Employee ID', 'First Name', 'Email', 'Last Name', 'Middle Name']
    available_fields_d1 = [field for field in fields if field in d1.columns and d1[field].notna().any()]
    available_fields_d2 = [field for field in fields if field in d2.columns and d2[field].notna().any()]
    total_score = 0
    matched_account = None

    for index1, row1 in d1.iterrows():
        if not row1.dropna().empty:
            scores = []
            matched_accounts = []  # Store the matched accounts for each row in d1
            
            for index2, row2 in d2.iterrows():
                if not row2.dropna().empty:
                    row_score = 0
                    for field1 in available_fields_d1:
                        if pd.notna(row1[field1]):
                            for field2 in available_fields_d2:
                                if pd.notna(row2[field2]):
                                    if len(available_fields_d1) > 4:
                                        #if str(row1[field1]).strip().lower() == str(row2[field2]).strip().lower()
                                        if str(row1[field1]).strip().lower() == str(row2[field2]).strip().lower() or str(row1[field1]).strip().lower() in str(row2[field2]).strip().lower():
                                            score = 1684
                                            row_score = score
                                            break
                                        else:
                                            sc = jellyfish.jaro_winkler_similarity(str(row1[field1]), str(row2[field2]))
                                            score = round(sc * 100)
                                            row_score += score
                                    else:
                                        sc = jellyfish.jaro_winkler_similarity(str(row1[field1]), str(row2[field2]))
                                        score = round(sc * 100)
                                        row_score += score
                    scores.append(row_score)
                    matched_accounts.append(row2)  # Store the matched account for each row in d2

            if scores:
                max_score = max(scores)
                max_index = scores.index(max_score)
                if max_score > total_score:
                    total_score = max_score
                    matched_account = matched_accounts[max_index]

    return scale_score(total_score), matched_account


weights = {
    'Employee ID': 5,
    'Email': 4,
    'First Name': 4,
    'Display Name': 5,
    'Last Name': 3,
    'Middle Name': 3
}

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(len(target_data)):
    print("\n\n================================")
    print("\n[+] Account : \n")
    print(target_data.iloc[i])

    matches = []
    top = []
    for ref in range(len(reference_data)):
        score, account = compare_dataframes(target_data.iloc[[i]], reference_data.iloc[[ref]], weights)
        matches.append((account, score))
    
    matches.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    top_scores = [match[1] for match in matches[:3]]
    print("--------------------------")
    print("Identities the Account matched with:")
    print("--------------------------")
    if len(matches) > 0:
        print(matches[0])
        print("Total Score: {}".format(matches[0][1]))
        print("-------\n")
  
    if len(matches) > 1:
        print(matches[1])
        print("Total Score: {}".format(matches[1][1]))
        print("-------\n")

    if len(matches) > 2:
        print(matches[2])
        print("Total Score: {}".format(matches[2][1]))
        print("-------\n")

    top_scores.sort(reverse=True)
    print("[+] Top Scores: " + ", ".join(map(str, top_scores)))

    row = {
        'Account': target_data.iloc[i],
        'Matched With': matches[0][0] if matches else None,
        'Comparison Score': matches[0][1] if matches else 0
    }

    new_df = pd.DataFrame([row])
    final = pd.concat([final, new_df], ignore_index=True)

print("\nExecution took: " + str(time.time() - start_time) + " seconds." + "\nTotal Accounts: " + str(len(target_data)))
```

I need to get the top 3 best matches. The problem is, In the compare_dataframes function, The if statement:  `if str(row1[field1]).strip().lower() == str(row2[field2]).strip().lower() or str(row1[field1]).strip().lower() in str(row2[field2]).strip().lower():` is not working correctly, I get 100 score on inaccurate matches and jaro winkler score on fields that should have been 100.

Example:

```
+] Account : 

Display Name                     bruce wayne
Employee ID                        NaN
First Name                       bruce
Email           batman@batcave.com
Last Name                          batcave
Middle Name                        NaN
Name: 1, dtype: object
--------------------------
Entities the Account matched with:
--------------------------
(Display Name                 bruce
Employee ID                        NaN
First Name                       bruce
Email           batman.ops@batcave.com
Last Name                          batcave
Middle Name                        NaN
Name: 12, dtype: object, 63.18289786223278)
Total Score: 63.18289786223278
-------
```

What I want is that it first check if the fields available are greater than 4, If so, Find an exact match between them. IF exact match is found, Score is set to maximum. Just as in the above output, Firstname Bruce should have matched with display name Bruce and returned a full match. Please help!

Comment: Please clarify which fields need to be greater than 4 and what how is the sore 4 computed, What do you mean by an exact match between them?  What is them?  Please include a sample of the input data as well as athe expected output resulting from your sample input.